# Code optimization for Google Sheets with date autofill

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Help please complete the code. The idea is that the date is automatically filled in the cell when the amount reaches zero. But the problem is that when the amount is calculated by the formula and reaches zero, the date does not appear, and if I manually put zero in this cell, everything works.

My code

```
// The column to check if something is entered.
const COLUMNTOCHECK = 20;
// Where the date timestamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
const DATETIMELOCATION = [0,-16];
// Sheet working on
const SHEETNAME = 'Sheet 1'

 
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME) {
    const selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK && e.value <= 0) {
      const dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: About `But the problem is that when the amount is calculated by the formula and reaches zero, the date does not appear, and if I manually put zero in this cell, everything works.`, in the current stage, the OnEdit trigger cannot detect the change of value by the formula. Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, in this case, if the value of the formula is changed by manually editing another cell, how about checking that cell?

Comment: This is my test sheet [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/100DcmndEyp29NqXlwCJYNF_tbu4k630hYu0oREhcIsA/edit?usp=sharing). I understand that the onEdit trigger only works when enter the value manually.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your reply and my comment. Can I ask you about the detail of your reply?

Comment: If the value in Column T is automatically updated by a formula, then the script should focus on the edited-row **value** in Column T; that is, the value updated by some data entry on another cell. The edited row = `e.range.rowStart`; so you want to evaluate `sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,20).getValue()`.

Comment: The essence of what I want to achieve is that in column T when the calculation by the formula will be - 0, so that in column D - the end date autofill. And it turns out that when it calculates according to the formula, the script doesn't react, and when I put 0 in the T column manually, everything works. Maybe the onEdit() trigger doesn't track the change in the formula. But I don't understand how to solve it.